# iPhone : little problem of memory leak with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, nstimer

suppose i have a button with an IBAction attached,  which triggers several actions when pressed, BUT have to trigger a particular action with a delay of one second, AND only if the user do not press the button a new time in this delay of one second.
The code looks like this :

```
   @interface Image : UIView {
           NSTimer *timer;
   }
   ...other things...;
   @end

   @implementation Image
   -(IBAction)startStopTimer{
   ...do something...;
   ...do something...;

   [timer invalidate];
   timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.7 
      target:self 
      selector:@selector(delayedAction) 
      userInfo:nil 
      repeats:NO] retain];
   }

   -(void)delayedAction{
   ...do other things...;
   }
   @end
```

As is, this code work very fine : "delaiAvance" is triggered only if the user DO NOT press the button one more time, and wait for at least one second.

The big problem is : each time the timer is fired, a memory leak occurs.

So, the question is : how and where do i have to release this NSTimer ?

([timer release] in dealloc method doesn't work.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, you don't retain `NSTimer` objects because they are retained by the 'system'. And by doing an `invalidate` you release it from the system.

Your best bet is probably to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` anyway, since this will allow you to cancel the trigger easily and you won't have to create a whole object to do it... If I understand your question correctly. To start the timer you'd do

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.7];
}

- (void)doSomething
{
     NSLog(@"Something happens now!");
}
```

The reason for the cancel is so that if you click the button again in the 0.7 second period, the 'timer' is canceled and a new one is created.

Comment: Hello Joe, many thanks for your advices ! it works like a charm ! I allready did a try with "performSelector", but i didn't know that i can cancel it ! You just made a little error in the syntax of the cancel : it should be "[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething) object:nil];" Thanks again !

Comment: ooops, silly me! I've amended it above for other people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> So, the question is: how and where do
>   i have to release this NSTimer?

You don’t. The run loop retains the timer for you and releases it some time after you call the `invalidate` method, so that all you have to do is droping the extra `retain` in the call to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`.

Comment: Since the OP retained it, they need to release it in `dealloc`.  That might not release it immediately if it is still scheduled to go off.

Comment: I’m telling him to drop the extra retain, that’s why I wrote there is no need for the release.

Comment: OK, the good way is below, with simply a "performselector". But still, if i drop the retain, the app crashes after few seconds...